# use of 'let' in passive voice

Tags: passive-voice, let

There are many grammar books which suggest that we can change active voice into passive voice by using *let*, but when we consult the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary, it refuses to form a passive sentence by using *let*. Why is this?

Comment: We can _use_ the verb _to let_ to form a clause in the passive voice, as in _"Do not misunderstand me"_ (active) and _"Let me not be misunderstood"_ (passive), but the verb _to let_ itself has no passive voice. That is all that OALD (and every other dictionary!) tells you.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, and thank you for your question. Please take the time to read our [**tour**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. They will help you to write a good question—and we hope you will ask more of them!

Comment: Can you provide an example from any of the books you mention?  As far as I know, *let* is independent of *voice*.  It's possible the books are confused about what constitutes "passive voice".

Comment: @Andrew The woods are full of them. Forming the passive imperative with _let_ is not as common today as it was in the past, so the OP may have an aged text. This is particularly the case in India, where ancient grammars are republished. See e.g. **[this.](https://books.google.com/books?id=N5Q_DAAAQBAJ&pg=PA167&dq=using+%22let%22+to+form+the+passive&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNxbjUyo7VAhVl_IMKHYmICZwQ6AEIKDAB#v=onepage&q=using%20%22let%22%20to%20form%20the%20passive&f=false)**

Comment: @P.E.Dant  Aha.  *"So let it be written; so let it be done."*  I guess it's fine if you want to talk like Yul Brynner.  However I would argue this is an *imperative* first, and *passive* second.

Comment: @Andrew We sometimes see questions here from Indian students who cite grammars written in the 19th (and occasionally the _18th_) century. They are public domain, and so are published at minimal cost. Considering that a fresh copy of CGEL goes for ~250USD, it's easy to see why a school in India might decide to pay 230RNI for a repirint of a victorian text.

Comment: We don't normally use "let" in passive voice. Try "allowed to" insead.. "She was allowed to go".

Comment: @user178049 We don't normally (even abnormally) use _let_ in the passive voice for a very good reason: it is impossible to do so! _Let_ does not have a passive voice. The OP is asking about something else: using _let_ to form a _passive imperative_.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the verb *to let* to form a clause in the passive voice, as in "Do not misunderstand me" (active) and "Let me not be misunderstood" (passive), but the verb *to let* itself has no passive voice. That is all that OALD (and every other dictionary!) tells you.  Forming the passive imperative with let is not as common today as it was in the past. --  [P. E. Dant](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/37009/p-e-dant)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that this use of "let" along with the passive "to be Xed" structure is considered *outdated* and is no longer in common use.  It is likely that the books you mention are old-fashioned and do not reflect modern English grammar.

However, it is worthwhile for the advanced English student to be familiar with this, so that they can understand it when it appear in older documents, or media that use archaic structures to give the work the proper historical "feeling".  For example, Yul Brynner as Pharaoh in the classic movie "The Ten Commandments" (1956)

> [So let it be written.  So let it be done.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4emcNAf5lY)

People didn't really talk this way in 1956, but this kind of language feels *archaic* as if it was the way this ancient Egyptian ruler might have talked (had he spoken English, of course).

That being said, I would call this a conversion to the **imperative**, using the passive voice to avoid specifying *who* should do the action.  This makes it suitable for things like religious texts, particularly those that specific things that should or should not be done.  It gives the commandments a kind of historical *gravitas*, and the lack of specificity makes the command apply to *everyone*.

For example this (made up) scripture:

> Let the cup be filled, and set on the table, and let no one drink from it, but instead let it be an offering to the Lord.

Again, I wouldn't recommend you use this grammar in ordinary conversation -- *except* perhaps ironically, as a kind of joke when talking informally with friends.